# How can I find the width of an image using PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I find the width of an image using php.

Comment: see you will find better - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890578/get-image-dimensions/18416721#18416721

Answer (score 12):

Easy, you can use [getimagesize](http://php.net/getimagesize):

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
```

Answer (score 4):

[getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use the GD libraries imagesx function, take a look at the manual page [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code, you can see more in www.php.net

To a file:

```
<?php
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
echo "<img src=\"img/flag.jpg\" $attr alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
?>
```

To URL:

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize("http://www.example.com/gifs/logo.gif");
$size = getimagesize("http://www.example.com/gifs/lo%20go.gif");

?>
```

Only you have to give an output to variable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `getimagesize()` you can get the dimensions from an image resource using `imagesx()` and `imagesy()`.

1. First of all you will have to download the image data using for example `file_get_contents()`
2. Then you create the image resource using `imagecreatefromstring()`
3. Finally get the image width with `imagesx()` and the image height with `imagesy()`.

   ```
   function get_image_dimensions($img_url=""){

           $image_dimensions=array();
           $image_dimensions['w']=0;
           $image_dimensions['h']=0;

           if($image_data=custom_file_get_contents($img_url)){

               $image_resource = imagecreatefromstring($image_data);
               $image_dimensions['w']=imagesx($image_resource);
               $image_dimensions['h']=imagesy($image_resource);
               imagedestroy($image_resource);
           }

           return $image_dimensions;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[Check here for official document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

```
list($Img_width, $Img_height) = getimagesize('Image Path');
echo "Width: " . $Img_width. "<br />";
echo "Height: " .  $Img_height;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 7.1 you can do:

```
[0 => $width, 1 => $height, 'mime' => $mime] = getimagesize($filename);
```

This eliminates the need to turn `$type` into mime-type, while retaining the elegant array style `list()` assignments.