# Get image dimensions

Tags: php, image, dimensions

I have an url to the image, like `$var = http://example.com/image.png`

**How do I get its dimensions to an array**, **like** `array([h]=> 200, [w]=>100)` `(height=200, width=100)`**?**

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can use the [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function like this:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('path to image');
echo "width: " . $width . "<br />";
echo "height: " .  $height;
```

Comment: OP did ask "How do I get its dimensions to an array" so Im not sure why this is the fully accepted answer... GJ though.

Comment: @Dutchie432: He mainly meant how to get image dimensions and creating an array once you have width and height is/should be easy :)

Comment: I think it's safe to say that's your (likely correct) assumption, and not addressing the specifics of the question.

Comment: This option does not support the https:// protocol. Anyone know of any good options for secure image size detection?

Comment: @JustinKaz It supports https, but your server needs to have openSSL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518616/76672 https is working well for me, for example.

Comment: @Dutchie432 `getimagesize` returns an array... `list` lists the array items out into variables.

Answer (score 45):

Using **getimagesize** function, we can also get these properties of that specific image-

```
<?php

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("image_name.jpg");

echo "Width: " .$width. "<br />";
echo "Height: " .$height. "<br />";
echo "Type: " .$type. "<br />";
echo "Attribute: " .$attr. "<br />";

//Using array
$arr = array('h' => $height, 'w' => $width, 't' => $type);
?>
```

**Result like this -**

Width: 200
Height: 100
Type: 2
Attribute: width='200' height='100'

**Type of image consider like -**

1 = GIF
2 = JPG
3 = PNG
4 = SWF
5 = PSD
6 = BMP
7 = TIFF(intel byte order)
8 = TIFF(motorola byte order)
9 = JPC
10 = JP2
11 = JPX
12 = JB2
13 = SWC
14 = IFF
15 = WBMP
16 = XBM

Answer (score 20):

```
<?php 
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize("http://site.com/image.png"); 
    $arr = array('h' => $height, 'w' => $width );
?>
```